# Prevent custom posts saving with the title 'Auto Draft'

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

How can I stop my custom posts saving with the title 'Auto Draft'? I've tried the code below to save my `Book_Title` custom field as the `post-title` but to no success:

```
if(isset($_POST['Book_Title'])){
    update_post_meta($post_id,'post_title', sanitize_text_field($_POST['Book_Title']));

    } else {
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'Book_Title' );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

please you test for stop Auto Draft :
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', false ); //in wp-config.php

if you use metabox :

1-

```
 function add_price_post_meta_box( $post ){ //use get_post_meta}
```

2-

```
function add_meta_box_price( $post_type, $post ){ 

add_meta_box(
    'meta_box_price', 

    'price',

    'add_price_post_meta_box',//for 1

    'post',

    'normal',
);
```

}

3-

```
function save_meta_box_price($post_id){//use update or delete post meta}
```

4-

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes','add_meta_box_price', 10, 2 );//call function 2 

 add_action( 'save_post', 'save_meta_box_price' ); //for save call function 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to change the default **post_title** WordPress uses when creating an auto-draft for your custom post type, the sample code below should work when added to a plugin or child theme. The code will only change the default *Auto Draft* post title for the identified custom post type while continuing to use "Auto Draft" for other post types. If you are trying to accomplish more than this, please explain further by updating your question or responding with a comment.

Like many WordPress hooks, the `title_save_pre` filter hook does not yet have a dedicated documentation page on wordpress.org.

If you are not familiar with creating your own plugin, you can refer to the [WordPress Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) and [WordPress Plugin Basics](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/#getting-started).

### Sample code

```php
function change_auto_draft_default_title( $title ) {
  $NEW_TITLE = 'New Default Title';
  $CUSTOM_POST_TYPE = 'your_custom_post_type';

  $post = \get_post();
  $post_type = $_GET['post_type'];

  if ( is_null( $post ) && 'Auto Draft' == $title && $CUSTOM_POST_TYPE == $post_type ) {
    $title = $NEW_TITLE;
  }

  return $title;
}
add_filter( 'title_save_pre', 'change_auto_draft_default_title', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in config file as per your need.

```
define( 'AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL',    3600 );     // autosave 1x per hour
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS',    false );    // no revisions
define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON',      true );
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS',     7 );        // one week
```